# Need to delete uploaded image file from image folder

Tags: laravel

I require to delete the uploaded image from the image folder. In fact, my image folder does not exist in the public directory. Basically, it falls under the project root directory, for example (projectfolder->images). Moreover, my JavaScript and CSS files also exist in the root directory. That's why I am using the `base_path()` function and returning the true file path, but an image is not deleting.

```php
public function deleteUploadGallery(Request $request)
{
    $name = $request->name;
    $authUser = Auth::User()->toArray();
    $match = ['user_id' => $authUser['id'], 
        'image_type' => 'gallery', 'image_name' => $name];
    
    $originalPath = base_path('images/' . $request->name);
    $thumbnailPath = base_path('images/thumbnail/' . $request->name);
    
    if (File::exists($originalPath)) {
        @unlink($originalPath);
    }
    if (file_exists($thumbnailPath)) {
        @unlink($thumbnailPath);
    }
    
    $userMedia = UsersInfoMedia::where($match)->first();
    $userMedia->delete();

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Image Deleted Successfully.']);
}
```

Comment: why do you have @ before unlink ?

Comment: I don't understand it clearly, are you asking why i am using unlink code before database delete? if this is your question, I am already using unlink code after added database delete code as well, but it is not working, moreover, i am checking this code with simple unlink() as well, but did not get the file deletion

Comment: basically my both if conditions (File::exists($originalPath))  and if(file_exists($thumbnailPath)) are not working, when code run it comes to the else condition.

Comment: that means your file path is incorrect? can you confirm it by logging the path and checking the value

Comment: actually I have printed and echo both variable $originalPath and $thumbnailPath, both return the true path. I am using these same paths in image upload as well, but when I use these paths for unlink it is not working

Comment: I don't see any @ sign in php manual for unlink : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php
 /// is this blade or laravel special thing, i asked to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used like this and it works perfectly for me

```
use File;
```

Above in header section

```
$originalPath  = getcwd()."/images/{$request->name}";

if(File::exists($originalPath)){
    File::delete($originalPath);
}
```

Comment: unlink(/home/myther8/public_html/officespace/images/1615822828109albertone.jpeg): No such file or directory" found.

I used File::delete() mehod as well, but file is not deleted

Comment: You are most welcome. I am very happy when someone get benefits for my efforts