# How can I delete the image once the row in the table is deleted?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I delete the image once the row in the table is deleted ?

Product controller :

Store function

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $product = new Product();

        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required|min:1',
            'tag' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = $request->name;
            $foldername = $request->name;
            $imagename = $filename .'.' . $request->image->extension();
            $path = public_path('images/produse/'. $filename .'/');

            if(!File::exists($path)){
                File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
            }

            Image::make($image)->resize(200, 200)->save( public_path('images/produse/' . $foldername .  '/' . $imagename ));
        }

        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->tag = $request->tag;
        $product->image = "/$foldername/$imagename";
        $product->save();

        return redirect('/products')->with('success', 'Produs adaugat cu succes !');
    }
```

Delete function

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $product->delete();

        return redirect('/products')->with('danger', 'Produs sters cu succes !');
    }
```

I want when I delete a product, to delete the folder with that image .. How can i do that ?

Comment: Get the `$product->image` before deleting and unlink/delete that file. [Deleting Files](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#deleting-files)

Answer (score 1):

If you're saving full path of an image to your product, you can check if file exists in public folder, and then delete it:

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
    {
        $image_path = public_path($product->image);
        if (File::exists($image_path)) {
           //File::delete($image_path) or;
           unlink($image_path);
        }
        $product->delete();

    return redirect('/products')->with('danger', 'Produs sters cu succes !');
}
```

Edit:

If you want to delete the whole folder, you can use:

```
File::deleteDirectory(public_path('path/to/your/folder'));
```

Comment: so it only deletes my picture, I would have liked everything with a folder :)): -?

Comment: I updated my answer, you can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You may use like this

```
use File;
```

Add above line in header section

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
{

    $originalPath  = getcwd()."/images/{$product-> image}";

    if(File::exists($originalPath)){
         File::delete($originalPath);
    }

    $product->delete();

    return redirect('/products')->with('danger', 'Produs sters cu succes !');
}
```

You follow this [Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66607615/need-to-delete-uploaded-image-file-from-image-folder/66610758#66610758)